# Importing a simple Javascript file in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I'm using the ionic 2 beta and I try to make a simple calculator for learning. I want to use the `math.js` library (http://mathjs.org) but I don't know how to import this file to use it in my typescript code.

For example:

```
export class HomePage
{
    constructor() {}

    calculate()
    {
        // Here I want to use math.js
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
export class HomePage
{
    var m = require('path/to/math.js');

    constructor() {}

    calculate()
    {
        m.math.parse(expression); // assuming expression is defined
    }
}
```

But I get the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'm.math.parse')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the script inside `index.html` like

`<script src="path/to/math.js"></script>`

Comment: It worked, thanks. I thought this wouldn't work because the index.html receives its information from the build folder.

Comment: Any different approach ?